# Restrict Terminal Server RDP session to paste from local clipboard to remote but not the other way around

Tags: rdp, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services, clipboard, clipboard-sharing

At our company, we use RDP sessions to a JumpHost/Gateway to access customer servers and databases and disallow leaking data to employees computers. This is enforced via group policy to disallow clipboard redirection (described [here](https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/disable-copy-and-paste-remote-desktop-win10-0007.html)).

But not being able to use the local clipboard to paste into the remote host is somewhat impractical. I've just discovered that the Mac »Microsoft Remote Desktop« app offers to switch between several »Clipboard modes« per host with the values `Disabled`, `Bidrectional`, `Local to Remote only` and `Remote to Local only`. So the `Local to Remote only` is the mode we need.

[image: Screenshot of a host configuration in Microsoft Remote Desktop showing Devices & Audio → Clipboard mode]

But how do we enforce that from the server? Is there a hidden group policy somewhere? I'm out of luck googling it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a Windows Server setting for this.  Unidirectional Clipboard is a feature of Citrix XenApp/XenDesktop.

https://james-rankin.com/articles/citrix-virtual-apps-and-desktops-clipboard-redirection/

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX217933/citrix-xenapp-and-xendesktop-how-to-configure-unidirectional-clipboard-redirection